# Table headings & page breaks not working in wkhtmltopdf

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

I'm using verison 0.12.5 of wkhtmltopdf on Debian Buster. I cannot get it to do any of the following behaviors that control table display and pagination with CSS declarations:

- Print table headers at the top of each page
- Control page orientation (setting to Landscape)
- Inserting a page break

The production table I am working with is very tall (100s of rows) and I need the table header to print at the top of each page. I would also like to avoid breaking in the middle of a row.

I have successfully gotten it to add a page break at the end of a table and I can specify the page orientation on the command line, but I need to control all of these behaviors using CSS (stylesheet or inline is fine) on the actual document.

Sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      thead { display: table-header-group }
      tfoot { display: table-row-group }
      tr { page-break-inside: avoid }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Title Here</h1>
  <div>
    <span id="filterModeLabel" class="FilterMode">Show all</span>
    <table>
    <thead>
        <tr><th>FirstName</th><th>LastName</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>John</td><td>Smith</td></tr>
        <tr><td>John</td><td>Smith</td></tr>
        <!-- Enough lines to push it onto two pages -->
        <tr><td>John</td><td>Smith</td></tr>
        <tr><td>John</td><td>Smith</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have also tried the following stylesheet variations with no luck:

```
@page {
  size: letter;
  size: landscape;
  margin-top: .40in;
  margin-left: .40in;
  margin-right: .40in;
  margin-bottom: .25in;
  font-size: 10px;
  @bottom-right { content: "Page " counter(page) " of " counter(pages)};
}
thead{
  display: table-header-group 
}
tfoot {
  display: table-row-group 
}
tr { 
  page-break-inside: avoid 
}

table {
  page-break-inside:auto; 
  word-wrap: break-word;
  page-break-after: always;
  border-collapse:collapse;

}
table tbody tr{ 
  page-break-inside:avoid; 
}
table.standard thead { 
  display:table-header-group;
  font-size: 12px; 
}
table tfoot { display: table-row-group; }
table tbody tr td
,table thead tr th {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 10pt; 
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

This is the call I am running on the command line:

```
wkhtmltopdf  p1.html  p1a.pdf
```

Here are screenshots of the result I get (top of pages 1 and 2):
[Top of page 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBW3e.png)
[Split between pages 1 and 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nV8SU.png)

Answer (score 1):

debian buster installs without patched QT
this resolved my issue.

wget https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/packaging/releases/download/0.12.6-1/wkhtmltox_0.12.6-1.buster_amd64.deb
apt install ./wkhtmltox_0.12.6-1.buster_amd64.deb